# SELECT DISTINCT with another table

Tags: postgresql

I want to use distinct to display my data.
But I don't know how to do it.This is my code.I want to display table gtest_version field max(poly_version)

```
select distinct on (rule_name) 
rule_name,rule_version,polyname,state 
from rule 
order by rule_name,rule_version DESC
```

[image]

Comment: And why aren't you using any of those columns in your code?. Can you post the table definition, and show a sample of the result set you want?

Comment: Could you explain your problem better? Examples of what you have and what you want to find would be good. Avoid the pictures, just write the tables.

Comment: But I think my picture is very clear that someone can answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct on (rule_name) 
  rule.rule_name,rule.rule_version,rule.polyname,rule.state, g.poly_version 
FROM  rule INNER JOIN gtest_version As g ON rule.polyname = g.polyname 
ORDER BY rule_name,g.poly_version DESC, rule_version DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to join the other table on `polyname` and then get the `max()` of `poly_version`, like

```
SELECT rule_name, rule_version, polyname, state, max(poly_version)
  FROM rule r JOIN gtest_version g ON r.polyname = g.polyname
 GROUP BY rule_name, rule_version, polyname, state
 ORDER BY rule_name, rule_version DESC;
```

However, your query and description does not tell how you want to pick the right row from the `rule` table.  My query will return all of these, while your `DISTINCT ON` will not...

Comment: error,polyname is ambiguous

Comment: You can always try to fix it youorself.  In this case you could simply pick a table alias (either r or g)...